# create c# dll runtime and after load runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

I have this problem:

I create in unity a dll with this code:

```
public bool PackScripts(string dllPath, string[] scripts)
{
    try
    {
        CodeDomProvider cc = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        var pf = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(string.Format(@"{0}\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll", pf));
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false; //generate executable
        cp.OutputAssembly = dllPath;
        CompilerResults cr = cc.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, scripts);
        return cr.Errors.Count == 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and works fine: if I create a solution with visual studio, include the dll created works fine!

but my goal is to load this dll dynamically.. to do this I use this code:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("packScripts.dll");
```

and here appears this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Unity/BundlesLoader/Assets/packscripts.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:746)
System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:728)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string)
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:576)
Loader+<LoadBundle>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Loader.cs:94)
```

Also if I create a new solution and try to use the same code, it gives the same error..
any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by loading the DLL dynamically? If you're wanting to work with plugins/mods, you might want to consider using something like MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework). Have a look at this video for more information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnE_PtJoHkA

Comment: I try to use a script from an assetbundle, so in this way when I create the assetbundle, it creates a dll, and I wish use it from the main project

Comment: Okay, so you have two separate projects, yeah? One in Unity, and one in VS. What is the reason for loading it dynamically, rather than including it in the project from the start?

Comment: hi @Eraph , I've 2 separate projects in unity, 'cause one is made from a modder somewhere and the other (core) is made from me and I need to import some gameobjects (and works) but also the scripts used in the project...